# How to calculate the area covered by a parametrized curve of a given thickness without self-intersections?

Tags: area, curves, parametrization

Given a curve $\gamma:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R^2,\ s\mapsto \vec\gamma(s)$ of thickness<sup>+</sup> $t$, what is the area covered by it for $s\in[a,b]$?

---

As a simple example, take a circle of radius $r\ge t$, $\vec\gamma(s) = (r\cos\tfrac sr, r\sin\tfrac sr)$, which therefore results in a ring between radii $r-t/2$ and $r+t/2$, i.e. the area is simply $(b-a)\left((1+t/2)^2-(1-t/2)^2\right) = (b-a)t$.
My approach so far:

The tangent unit vector is given as

$$\vec T(s) = \vec\gamma'(s)$$

(where ' denotes derivation as usual, if $s$ is actually parametrizing by arc length such that $|\vec\gamma'|\equiv1$), and the normal unit vector can be obtained using the first of the [Frenet-Serret formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenet%E2%80%93Serret_formulas) as

$$\vec N = \frac1\kappa\vec T'$$

with curvature $\kappa = |\vec T'|$. For every $s$ we therefore get the line

$$\vec l(s,u) = \vec\gamma(s) + u\cdot\vec N(s), \quad u\in\left[-\tfrac t2, \tfrac t2\right]$$

The sought area is then obtained by integrating $|\vec l(s,u)|$ weighted *somehow* with probably the curvature, but that's the part where I'm currently stuck. And things get worse for changes in curvature direction (where $\kappa=0$), and I don't have an idea how to properly treat overlapping areas and loops etc...

---

<sup>+</sup> I'm not sure if the "intuitive" definition of this is enough, I mean for every $s$ the normal at $\vec\gamma(s)$ is extended by $\pm t/2$

Comment: Your expression fot the area in the case of the circle isn't correct.  Assuming the units of $\  s\ $ are radians, the area should be $\ (b-a)rt\ .$ if the units of $\  s\ $ were degrees, the area would be $\ \frac{\pi(b-a)rt}{180}\ .$ Note that in your formula $\ \vec{\gamma}(s)=(r\cos s, r\sin s)\ $ for the paramaterisation of the circle, the parameter $\ s\ $ is *not* arc length.  The parameterisation with respect to arc length is
$$
\vec{\gamma}(s)=\left(r\cos\frac{s}{r},\sin\frac{s}{r}\right)\ .
$$
With that parametetisation, the formula for the area would be $\ (b-a)t\ .$

Comment: @lonzaleggiera Thanks, I fixed this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\def\ed{\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}}\\
\def\vg{\vec{\gamma}}\\
\def\vl{\vec{l}}\\
\def\vn{\vec{N}}\\
\def\vt{\vec{T}}$
If you parameterise the curve $\ \vec{\gamma}\ $ with its arc length $\ s\ ,$ and the condition
\begin{align}
&\vg\big(s_1\big)+u_1\vn\big(s_1\big)=\vg\big(s_2\big)+u_2\vn\big(s_2\big),\\
&s_1,s_2\in[a,b],u_1,u_2\in{\scriptsize\left[{-}\frac{t}{2},\frac{t}{2}\right]}\\
\iff&s_1=s_2, u_1=u_2\label{eq1}\tag{c1}
\end{align}
(i.e. no part of the thickened curve ever intersects any other part) is satisfied, then the formula for the area of the closed subset
$$
A\ed\left\{\vg(s)+u\vn(s)\,\left|\,a\le s\le b,{\small{-}\frac{t}{2}}\le u\le{\small\frac{t}{2}}\right.\right\}
$$
of $\ \mathbb{R}^2\ $ enclosed within the lines
\begin{align}
&\big\{\vg(a)+u\vn(a)\,\big|\ u\in{\scriptstyle\left[{-}\frac{t}{2},\frac{t}{2}\right]}\big\}\ \ \ \text{ and}\\
&\big\{\vg(b)+u\vn(b)\,\big|\ u\in{\scriptstyle\left[{-}\frac{t}{2},\frac{t}{2}\right]}\big\}\ ,
\end{align}
and the curves
\begin{align}
&\left\{\vg(s)-{\small\frac{t}{2}}\vn(s)\,\left|\,s\in[a,b]\right.\right\}\ \ \ \text{ and}\\
&\left\{\vg(s)+{\small\frac{t}{2}}\vn(s)\,\left|\,s\in[a,b]\right.\right\}
\end{align}
is exactly the same as it is for the circle, namely
$$
(b-a)t\ .
$$
The area of $\ A\ $ is, by definition,
$$
\iint_A1\,dxdy\ ,
$$
which can be evaluated by using the [multivariate change of variable formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Substitution_for_multiple_variables) for the change of variables from $\ x,y\ $ to $\ s,u\ .$ From the condition (\ref{eq1}), it follows that the mapping $\ \vl:[a,b]\times\left[{-}\frac{t}{2},\frac{t}{2}\right]\rightarrow A\ ,$ given by
$$
\vl(s,u)\ed\vg(s)+u\vn(s)
$$
is a differentiable bijection, so its [Jacobian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant)
\begin{align}
J(s,u)&\ed\pmatrix{\frac{\partial\vl}{\partial s}(s,u)&\frac{\partial\vl}{\partial u}(s,u)}\\
&=\pmatrix{\vg\,'(s)+u\vn\,'(s)&\vn(s)}\\
&=\pmatrix{\big(1-u\kappa(s)\big)\vg\,'(s)&\vn(s)}\\
&=\pmatrix{\big(1-u\kappa(s)\big)\vt(s)&\vn(s)}
\end{align}
must be non-singular, and its Jacobian determinant
$$
\det J(s,u)=(1-u\kappa(s))\det\pmatrix{\vt(s)&\vn(s)}
$$
must be non-zero over $\ (a,b)\times\left({-}\frac{t}{2},\frac{t}{2}\right)\ .$ It follows from this that
$$
0\le \kappa(s)\le\frac{2}{t}\label{eq2}\tag{c2}
$$
for all $\ s\in(a,b)\ $, since otherwise $\ \left(s,\frac{1}{\kappa(s)}\right)\ $ would be a point in $\ (a,b)\times\left({-}\frac{t}{2},\frac{t}{2}\right)\ $ where $\ \det J\left(s,\frac{1}{\kappa(s)}\right)\ $ vanished.

Now, by the above-mentioned change of variable formula,
\begin{align}
\iint_A1\,dxdy&=\int_a^b\int_{{-}\frac{t}{2}}^\frac{t}{2}|\det J(s,u)|\,du\,ds\\\
&=\int_a^b\int_{{-}\frac{t}{2}}^\frac{t}{2}\big|1-u\kappa(s)\big|\left|\det\pmatrix{\vt(s)&\vn(s)}\right|\,du\,ds\\
&=\int_a^b\int_{{-}\frac{t}{2}}^\frac{t}{2}\big(1-u\kappa(s)\big)\,du\,ds\\
&=(b-a)t\ ,
\end{align}
where $\ \big|1-u\kappa(s)\big|=1-u\kappa(s)\ $ for $\ u\in\left({-}\frac{t}{2},\frac{t}{2}\right)\ $ by virtue of inequality (\ref{eq2}), and $\ \big|\det\pmatrix{\vt(s)&\vn(s)}\big|=1\ $ because $\ \vt(s)\ $ and $\ \vn(s)\ $ are orthogonal unit vectors.

Comment: Thanks! I'll need some time to comprehend your answer, but it looks good at a first glance. But some first questions: I think the $\frac12\vec N$ should be $\frac t2\vec N$ above, and I'm not sure where $\vec N'$ went in $J(s,u)$, according to Frenet-Serret that should lead to the binormal unit vector appearing, since $\vec N' = -\kappa\vec T + \tau\vec B$ (unless there is no torque $\tau$, which might relate to the non-intersecting requirement btw, but since $\vec B=\pm\vec e_z$ the sign swap might occur for singular $s_0$ where $\kappa(s_0)=0$, right?).

Comment: I'll spend some more time on this later, but your result looks interesting yet baffling at the same time

Comment: Yes, you're right about the $\ \frac{t}{2}\ .$ It was a typo which I've now fixed.  Thank you for picking it up. The torsion is zero because the curve is planar.

Comment: Thanks! I've restricted the question to the non-intersecting case now, such that your answer can be fully accepted, and opened a [new question for the intersecting case](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4824726/163). It's interesting that the symmetric thickness cancels out the curvature dependent term, so the result boils down to "arc-length times thickness". I wonder if this can be generalized to a $d-1$-dimenstional ball perpendicular to a $d$-dimensional curve as "hypersurface times arc-length" or if there torque and higher-dimensional parameters make matters more complicated...